# flask app run in docker container not reachable from host

Tags: docker, flask

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV LANG C.UTF-8 
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/flask_venv
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
ENV FLASK_ENV development

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y python3 python3-venv net-tools
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV

COPY . /opt/my_app
WORKDIR /opt/my_app
RUN python3 -m pip install wheel
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5656
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

This is how I run the container:

```
docker run --name flask_container -d -p 5001:5656 flask_app:0.0.1
```

This is my app.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc", host="0.0.0.0", port=5656)
```

When I go to https://localhost:5001 in my browser, no connection can me made to the app (Chrome: This site can’t be reached).

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**

Complete app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

from flask_migrate import Migrate

from app_directory import app_factory, db
from cli_commands import register

app = app_factory(os.getenv("ENV_VAR") or "dev")
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

register(app, db)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc", host="0.0.0.0", port=5656)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with this dockerfile:

```
# docker build . -t flask_app
# docker run --name flask_container -p 4567:5000 flask_app
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV LANG C.UTF-8 
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/flask_app/flask_venv
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
ENV FLASK_ENV development

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y python3 python3-venv

RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV

RUN groupadd -r flask_group && useradd -r -m -g flask_group flask_user

COPY . /opt/flask_app/my_app
WORKDIR /opt/flask_app/my_app
RUN python3 -m pip install wheel
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN chown -R flask_user:flask_group /opt/flask_app
USER flask_user

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

I think exposing the port was problematic, but I am still not 100% what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug your docker container, I suggest not to use the `-d` flag, unless you are absolutely sure everything works how it is supposed to.

In your case, if you remove the `-d` flag you will see that your python script is incomplete:

```
docker run --rm --name flask_container -p 5001:5656 so
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc", host="0.0.0.0", port=5656)
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

A quick fix would be to have the following `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc", host="0.0.0.0", port=5656)
```

After rebuilding the image, this leads now to:

```
docker run --rm --name flask_container -p 5001:5656 so
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on https://0.0.0.0:5656/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 423-289-631
```

Now you can restart the container with `-d` :)

```
docker run --rm --name flask_container -d -p 5001:5656 so
2c777b21c96f080c05df714c339c80ca88c9943e64cc0de12d05544c3d81faba
apoehlmann:~/workspace/teststuff/stackoverflow$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
2c777b21c96f        so                   "python3 app.py"         3 seconds ago       Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:5001->5656/tcp              flask_container
```

Comment: sorry, my post was incomplete. I edited the question: I only posted the portion of the app.py that I thought was relevant.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid without any stack trace of yours I can't really help you. You also seem to have python dependencies that don't allow to replicate your container, i.e. custom modules. From the minimal python script I used based on your post however, there doesn't seem to be an issue with the docker setup. So I would assume something is wrong with your python script.

Comment: It's strange, because outside of the docker container, it works and when I start the container without -d, the output tells me, the app is listening on the port. I just cannot access it from outside the container. Is there any way to check from inside the docker container whether it is reachable from the outside?